# parse [object Object] Angular 6

Tags: json, angular, jsonparser

I want to parse a string and save `projectName` and `poNumber` into 2 variables. This is what I have by now, using JSON.parse()

```
employees = []
JSON.parse(data).array.forEach(element => {
    this.employees.push({
      projectName: element.projectName,
      poNumber: element.poNumber
    })
  });

console.log(employees['projectName'])
console.log(employees['poNumber'])
```

where `data` has this format:

`{"id":1,"name": "john doe", "project":"[object Object]"}`

and `project` looks like:

```
"project": [
     {
        "projectName": "proj1",
        "poNumber": "1"
     }
]
```

But I get this error

> ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Where am I mistaking? Thank you for your time!

EDIT: I understood why I get this error, because my data is already an object and there is no need to use `JSON.parse()`, but my code is still not working because I get the error:

> core.js:1671 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of
>   undefined

Comment: whats is [object Object] in data?

Comment: This is how my entry looks into my database, I posted it using postman, but `project` has the format I wrote in my question.

Comment: Can you add console in `element` and post consoled data into your question.

Comment: try ```data.project.forEach```.

Comment: use JSON.parse(data.project). //logic and check project list is valid or not. ie. it is  properly formatted or not using JSON.stringify()

Comment: I get `data.project.forEach is not a function`, because `data.project` looks like `[object Object]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Json String is not valid and is not stringified by JSON.stringify() instead it was stringified by toString method, otherwise nested objects were stringified properly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you made me realize what I did wrong. I have to save the data first with JSON.stringify(x)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I didn't parse the right thing. Here is the correct snippet:

```
let p = JSON.parse(data.project);

  this.employees.push({
  projectName: p.projectName,
  poNumber: p.poNumber
})
```

Thank you everyone for help! Every answer of you was right.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
JSON.parse(data).array.forEach(element => {
  this.employees.push({
    projectName: element.project.projectName,
    poNumber: element.project.poNumber
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error in JSON format, but after validating it on online JSON validator it seems perfect. On the basis of that I have created following example which shows two diffrent ways to get data in your "employees" array.

I hope this will be helpful.

```js
let data = {
 "id":1,"name":"john doe",
  "project":[
        {
  "projectName": "proj1",
  "poNumber": "1"
 },
        {
  "projectName": "proj2",
  "poNumber": "2"
 }
    ]
};

let employees = [];


Object.keys(data).map(key => {
    if(key === 'project') {
        // Method 1
        // ===========================
        data[key].map(obj => {
            employees.push(obj);
        });
        
        // Method 2 : Shorter method
        // ===========================
        employees.push(...data[key]);
    }
});

console.log('Employees :', employees);
```

Thanks,
Jignesh Raval

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse(data).array.forEach(element => {
     this.employees.push({
        projectName: element.project.projectName,
        poNumber: element.project.poNumber
     })
});
```

Comment: A good answer has a better explanation [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)